# How to store this list as individual data's in Django database?

Tags: python, django, operating-system

I have a `subprocess` code like this:

```
final_list = subprocess.Popen(['ls', destination], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines()
```

This returns the directory as a list:

```
['genelaytics', '__init__.py', '__init__.pyc', 'settings.py', 'wsgi.pyc']
```

Now I want to calculate the size of each file and insert the file as individual elements in database along with size and other attributes. I tried using for loop:

```
for list in final_list:     
        st = os.stat(list)
        size = st.st_size 
        b = File(file_name=list, source=test_url, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, size=size)
        b.save()
```

I am getting this error while running the above code:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/zurelsoft/workspace/genelaytics/fileupload/views.py" in sync
  94.         st = os.stat(list)

Exception Type: OSError at /sync/
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '__init__.py'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing just the filename (i.e.`'__init__.py'`), not the full path (i.e. `'/module/__init__.py'`) to `os.stat()`

I suggest doing something like so:

```
>>> folder = '/Python27/Doc'
>>> files = os.listdir(folder)
>>> for filename in files:
    fullname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    print fullname, os.path.getsize(fullname)


/Python27/Doc\python27.chm 5754439
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped. I have a problem with database insertion though. It inserts all the data many times.

Comment: My pleasure. Could you write up your problem in a new question?

Answer (score 0):

you need to prepend the base directory location (`os.dirname(__file__)` ... (probably)) ,to the filename before you stat it ...